# Как можно привязать и открыть одну форуму в другой

Tags: c#

Как можно привязать и открыть одну форуму в другой, тоесть как настройки программы допустим, что-бы не было такового когда ты перемещаешь основную форму на форма с настройками не двигалась, так-же и наоборот. Что нужно использовать для такого WPF или Windows Form? Искал такое, не нашел.

Comment: вам надо MDI смотреть или Popup Windows. По вашему тексту трудно понять, что вам надо в итоге.

Comment: а форма настроек, должна всегда отображаться на основной форме?

Comment: WPF+MDI, но я не понял вопроса.